# Chat functionality in django Helpdesk web application

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develope a Helpdesk application with django. It is a basic app that allows users to authenticate and submit support tickets. Everything works fine upto submitting the tickets, but now I want to add the chat functionality where the support staff can reply to user's queries and they can communicate back and forth.

I'm relatively new to development and coding, so can't think like a pro, but I'm hoping that some of you experts out there can give me a general idea how to approach this?

I've spent so much time to get to this point but now I'm kind of stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my TicketUpdateView where users with staff status can update the tickets. It's not fully functional but I'm just putting it out for you guys to have some idea.

File **\helpdesk\tickets\views.py**

```
class TicketUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Ticket
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        user =self.request.user
        if user.is_staff:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: You might be interested in [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) for this

Comment: Yes Django Channels is the best option. If you are a beginner than you can also use simple table to store messages against two users and display them in a chat via jquery ajax.

Comment: there are some 3rd party services for this. Creating this yourself is probably too complicated for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Here is a websocket based chat application which you can use.

https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat

but this one allows any user of your website to chat with any other user. If you want to restrict this, and allow users to chat only with agents and not with other users, you may have to modify the behavior.